# How to replace multiple documents in one DB call

Tags: rethinkdb

I have an array of existing documents in Rethink. They all have an ID field. What I want to do is basically this (in javascript):

```
r.table('my_table').replace(myArrayOfDocuments);
```

When I try that I get an error saying: `Inserted value must be an OBJECT (got ARRAY)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a list of objects you want to replace, something like this should work:

```
r.expr(myArrayOfDocuments)
 .forEach(function(row) { return r.table('my_table').get(row('id'))
                                                    .replace(row); })
 .run(conn, callback);
```

This assumes your primary key is `id`, but if you want a more generic solution, you can replace `id` with `r.table('my_table').info()('primary_key')`.

The reason the query you posted doesn't work is that `r.table('my_table').replace(...)` is trying to replace every row in your table with the argument you gave it - in this case, an array rather than the expected dict.  Normally `r.table('my_table').replace(...)` should be given a function to generate the new row based on the old row.  See the [documentation for `replace`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/replace/) for more details or examples.

Comment: Thanks Tryneus! This looks like exactly what I needed. I don't have enough rep to upvote you but I did mark as accepted. Thanks again!